# OfflineDownload Map Package for Country SKMaps

Tags: ios, skmaps

I was running the Framework Demo application given by skobbler on my iPhone. I tried to download United States offline maps but the download din't start. In the log it says : 
Invalid property type for propertyName downloadType. Skip 
 didstartDownload

but the progress bar and the percent label does not get updated.I am not sure if download has started or not.The delegate methods are also not getting called for download manager. Whereas if I am trying to download India offline map, then it is getting downloaded with continuous progress bar and label updating. What is this issue?
Currently I am using Free SDK version. Is this something related to licence key or what I dont know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in the demo project - you actually should not have a "download" option on UnitedStates. Due to size constraints there is no one package for US but you would need to download the map packages for all the 50 states.

We will fix the demo project in the following SDK update.

If you want to download the whole US map - check the maps.json or maps.xml file and download the corresponding packages for all the states.

Comment: Great..Thanks a lot.Now I will download all the 50 states map for US. Is this issue there with any other country?

Comment: Not that I know of - in any case the maps.xml or maps.json file should provide all the answers